# Assist with bash loop using files

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'd like some help with this script I'm working on to utilize the AWS CLI. My goal is to get a list of instances base on tags. So far I have what want. However, I'd like some help with interating not only through my initial file, but again through another file.

Here's what I've tried, it's not pretty but it does the job for me. I need some assistance finishing it:

```
FILENAME="aws_regions.txt"
AWSREGIONS=$(cat $FILENAME)

for region in $AWSREGIONS
do
    echo "\nListing hosts in region:'$region'..."
    aws ec2 describe-instances --filters "Name=tag:name,Values=test" --output text --query 'Reservations[].Instances[].[InstanceId, PrivateIpAddress, Tags[?Key==`Name`].Value[] | [0]]' --region $region --profile default

done
```

I would like to run this through a list of profiles I have saved in a text file. How would I do so? I'm not sure how I would replace `--profile default` with the list in the file.

Comment: Perhaps: `while read region; do while read profile; do echo $region:$profile; done < profiles.txt; done < aws_regions.txt`. (replace echo with the appropriate command)

Comment: See https://www.shellcheck.net/wiki/SC2013